# $(document).width() not updating on browser resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, document

I have found that when I resize the window (various browsers) $(document).width() frequently does not update.  Is this a known issue, or is something funky going on?  If it's a known issue, what's the workaround?

EDIT: All of a sudden (as if by magic) the exact same page's document width is updating, but it's inconsistent.  For example I made the page wider and the alert telling me the width said it got smaller. (this happened in Firefox)

Comment: The issue you are describing (`document`'s width() reporting inconsistent results) may be a result of... `document`'s real width changing inconsistently (like problem with the JS, that sometimes changes the width, sometimes not). I have experienced it eg. lately with someone else's code that was having weird combination of element resizing, AJAX calls and `setTimeout` (which all together caused different results depending on whether the AJAX call returned before `setTimeout` callback was called).

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(window).width()`, as this is what you are looking for.

You can see the difference eg. by looking at the official [jQuery's `.width()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Comment: No it's not.  I need the document width, because it needs to include space covered in scroll bars.  The window is the size of the viewport.

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp: Based on your question I assumed you are asking about viewport. Document not adjusting to window may have several different causes - for example may be a result of adjusting the styles in JS only on page load. Did you check and are 100% positive that the width of the document changes is the cases you mentioned?

Comment: Yup.  The background wrap is set to 100% width, so it -should- be resizing. :/

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp: I understand it should, but so far seemingly it does not (causes may be multiple). Try to reproduce the issue and check with Firebug (in Firefox) or Developer Tools (Chrome/Chromium), what is the width of the document reported by such tools in such case. It may give you some insight on whether the `document` just did not resize (very likely) or `width()` reports the value incorrectly (which is a lot less likely to happen).